# How to download latest version of pnp webparts sppkg files?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I want to download latest build of sp-dev-fx-webparts. I need sppkg file, where I can find latest build of pnp webparts?

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-list-form

Answer (score 0):

`.sppkg` files for SPFx samples are not provided directly for some obvious reasons. Check the replies from repository moderator on [this thread](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/1731).

So, you have to clone the GitHub repository, build the web part & create a solution using below commands for which you the package file:

```
npm install
gulp build
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

**Related article**: [Walkthrough: how to deploy spfx sample webparts](https://sharepointstuff.com/2019/06/17/how-to-deploy-spfx-sample-webparts/)